# How to run a method in terminal/command prompt using python

Tags: python

I have the file1 here:

```
#File1

class MyClass1():
  def abc(self)
   ---

  def efg(self)
   ---
```

and here's the file2:

```
#File2
from File1 import MyClass1

def test1()
  callfromfile1 = Myclass1()
  callfromfile1.abc()

def test2()
  callfromfile1 = Myclass1()
  callfromfile1.efg()

if __name__== "__main__":
  test()
```

Prob:
How to call `test2` method only in terminal/command prompt?

note: 
1. I'm using python3
2. Should I need to add another "class (eg. MyClass2)" above in `file2` in order to call the `test2` specicifically? 
3. Please give some example for reference.

Comment: Apart from the import `from selenium import webdriver` is there anything related to `selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what syntax is specifically for python and selenium since i'm using this for selenium testing. thnx

Comment: It is a pure `Pythonic` concept and have no relation with `Selenium`. Update the question dropping the line `from selenium import webdriver` and `selenium` tag to clear up the confusion

Comment: done! thnx for noticing it.

Comment: Are you willing to pass additional command line arguments to the script?

Comment: hmm don't know if I understand your question. but I only need to run the `test2` method and not need any data to pass-on.

Comment: I try calling `test2` key-ing syntax in the command promt:
`python3 File2.Myclass1.test2` but it returns `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Tangentially, `test2` is not inside `Myclass1`, but changing that won't help; like the error message tells you, Python only accepts a file name as its first argument.

Answer (score 1):

If `file2` is actually called `file2.py` and is in your `PYTHONPATH` you can say

```
python3 -c 'import file2; test2()'
```

If not, maybe try

```
(cat file2; echo 'test2()') | python3
```

A third possible solution is to make the last clause more complex.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        test()
    elif 'test2' in sys.argv[1:]:
        test2()
    # maybe more cases here in the future
```

and call it like

```
python3 file2 test2
```

to take the `elif` branch.

Comment: As an aside, a library called [`click`](https://pypi.org/project/click/) makes it very easy to expose individual functions inside a Python source file to a calling shell.

Comment: Yes, it is the actual file named `file1.py` and `file2.py`